# .bind not working for dynamically creating id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind to dynamically changing id , the code works fine for static id but once i used to bind dynamically its not binding .

```
$("#placeholder"+id).bind("\""+"plothover"+id+"\"", function (event, pos, item) {--some code here --}
```

If use in this way it works fine

```
$("#placeholder"+id).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {--some code here --}
```

Comment: Did you check browser console for any error?

Comment: why this - `"\""+"plothover"+id+"\""` ? is this some kind of eventType

Comment: I just want to bind dynamic id ....i tried in that way ......is any possible workout to bind dynamic changing id ? thnxs

Answer (score 2):

This is due to bind not working for dynamic elements, taken from the jQuery site:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in
>   the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call
>   to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion
>   of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

The solution here is to use the `.on` method.

We also need to know which event you want to catch, bind is binding an event to an element, such as "click". At the minute, you seem to not be binding to any specific event.

Comment: In this case i am using flot to plot graph and i am binding the graph to the crosshair so as to get values ....Thnxs for ur answer but able to catch how will .on method would work >>

Comment: I guess you need the "onmouseover" event then. Look up the .on method on the jQuery site, it'll give you all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Try by including "live" method instead of "bind".

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'on' function:

use as bind - `$(el).on('event name',callback);`

use as live - `$(el parent).on('event name','element selector',[may be some data],callback)`

namespace - `$(el).on('namespace.event',callback)`

data - `$(el).on('event',{col: varCol},callback)`

Comment: Thnxs for suggestion .........but here 'event name' is not fixed it could be 'event name1' or 'event name2'..........any suggestion how to apply in that case ..

Comment: Hm... I see two solutions: first - use namespaces $(el).on('namespace.event',...) where namespace id your id, second - use one event name and append data to event: $(el).on('event',{col: varCol}, callback)

Answer (score 0):

If your element is not yet created `.bind()` will not work! You have to use `.live()`

http://api.jquery.com/live/

It binds the event one time on the parent element and you handle all child events from there. It's the right approach and that way you have just one event on the parent which prevents memory leaks if you don't remove properly the dynamic elements.

Ooops:

`As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().`

But it still doing the same stuff : )